# How do you remove a community wiki tag that I clicked on by accident

Tags: support, community-wiki

If I made a mistake and checked the "community wiki" flag by mistake [when answering a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15203/versioning-with-arcsde-is-it-possible-to-cancel-or-reject-edits-once-theyve-be). How do I remove that and leave it as my answer? Would that give me my points back? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the wiki status from that answer. In general you can flag for moderator attention on your answer if you accidentally mark your answer as wiki.

(note there are certain circumstances with lots of editing or many different users editing where an answer will *automatically* become wiki and these are not reversible.)

Great answer btw!

Comment: thanks for the help!